# Finding the first row of zeros n x n array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, goto, zero

I have some pseudocode that finds the first all-zero row in an nxm matrix:

```
int first_zero_row = -1; /* none */
int i, j;
for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
       if (A[i][j]) goto next;
    }
    first_zero_row = i;
    break;
next: ;
}
```

While this should work, I don't think using a goto statement is the best way to go. I'm not very familiar with C but my goal is to have the code as well structured in C as possible. Would this be the best way to go about it, or is there a faster or more general way?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with goto but there are other ways to write this if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Extracting this into a function of its own will let you use `return i` in favor of two `break` statements.

Comment: Doesn't C have a `continue` statement? (That said I would avoid using both in a single block, and this is an obvious candidate for a function that returns `true` or `false` depending on whether it finds an all-zero row.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `first_zero_row` only when the inner loop ran to completion,

```
int first_zero_row = -1; /* none */
int i, j;
for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
       if (A[i][j]) break;
    }
    if (j == n) {
        first_zero_row = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

if you want to avoid the `goto`.

Answer (score 0):

Place `break;` statement instead of goto statement. Set a boolean flag and check for the flag and if the flag is true, then break again from outer for loop too. Something like this -

```
bool nonZeroFlag = true;

for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
   for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
     if (A[i][j]){
        nonZeroFlag = false;
        break;
     }
   }
  if (nonZeroFlag) {
     first_zero_row = i;
     break;
  }
  nonZeroFlag = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int first_zero_row = -1; /* none */
int i, j;
for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
       if (A[i][j] != 0){
           first_zero_row = i;
       } 
    }
    break;
next: ;
}
```

how about this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one with no `break` or `goto` :)

```
int zero_count = -1; /* none */
i = j = 0;
for(i=0; i < n && (zero_count != n); i++) {
    for (j=0; j < n && (A[i][j] == 0); j++) {
       zero_count = j + 1;
    }
}

if(i < 10)
   printf("First Zero row is %d\n",i);
else
   printf("Nop! Not today!\n");
```